# Evaluate $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n F_{2n}}{9^n},$ where $F_{2n}$ is the nth Fibonacci number

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

Evaluate $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n F_{2n}}{9^n},$ where $F_{n}$ is the $n^{th}$ fibnocci number

My idea:

if $a(n)$ is an eventually monotone decreasing sequence, converging to 0, here $a(n) = \frac{ F_{2n}}{9^n},$

but how do we find sum of this series, thank you

Answer (score 2):

Using https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Binet%27s_Formula

The summation, $$=(-1/9)^n\frac{a^{2n}-b^{2n}}{a-b}=\dfrac{\sum(-a^2/9)^n-\sum(-b^2/9)^n}{a-b}$$

where $a,b$ are the roots of $$t^2-t-1=0$$

Now both are https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Infinite_geometric_series